# Remove rows of one Dataframe based on one column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two DataFrame and want remove rows in df1 where we have same value in column 'a' in df2. Moreover one common value in df2 will only remove one row.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,3,4,4],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'c':[6,5,4,3,2,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,4,2],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[6,5,4]})
result = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3,4],'b':[1,2,4,6],'c':[6,5,3,1]})
```

Comment: Check with isin ~

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) + [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to create a boolean mask and use this mask to filter the rows from `df1`:

```
m = df1['a'].isin(df2['a']) & ~df1['a'].duplicated()
df = df1[~m]
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  6
1  1  2  5
3  3  4  3
5  4  6  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,3,4,4],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'c':[6,5,4,3,2,1]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,4,2],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[6,5,4]})
df2a = df2['a'].tolist()
def remove_df2_dup(x):
    if x in df2a:
        df2a.remove(x)
        return False
    return True
df1[df1.a.apply(remove_df2_dup)]
```

It creates a list from `df2['a']`, then checks that list against each value of `df1['a']`, removing values from the list each time there's a match in `df1`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,3,4,4],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'c':[6,5,4,3,2,1]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,4,2],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[6,5,4]})

for x in df2.a:
    if x in df1.a:
        df1.drop(df1[df1.a==x].index[0], inplace=True)

print(df1)
```